# Many same Closure Compiler watcher tasks in WebStorm at the same time

Tags: webstorm, google-closure-compiler, file-watcher

In WebStorm, my project is a library made up of 10 js files and Closure Compiler, as file watcher in WebStorm, compiles the files in a single one.

Arguments for Closure Compiler file watcher are `... --js 1.js --js 2.js ... --js 10.js --js_output_file mylib.min.js ...`

When I modify one of these files and save it, I can see immediately in WebStorm "background tasks", 1 new item "Executing 'Closure Compiler' task..." and this is fine.

**The problem**: when I modify many files and do a "Save", many "Executing 'Closure Compiler' task..." appear in "background tasks" (ex: 5 tasks if 5 files modified). All tasks are doing the same 10 file compilation although 1 task only is required. My computer is out of control (100% CPU) for a while and I have to cancel all the tasks except one to get it completed faster.

WebStorm launches a watcher task for each modified file and doesn't understand that launching many identical tasks at the same time is pointless.

**Is there a way to get a single watcher task although many file modified ?**
If not, is there at least a way to avoid a "100% CPU" issue (ex: decrease the WebStorm process priority) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution from Alexander Doroshko at JetBrain:

Remove any file-specific macros (those that start with $File ) in the File Watcher settings (specifically 'Arguments' and 'Working directory' field).

`$FileDir` is by default in the 'Working directory' field, I removed it and hardcoded the path instead.

I have indeed now a single task although many files changed.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not currently possible unfortunately; please follow [WEB-14086](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14086) for updates

Comment: Waiting for a fix, is it possible to avoid the 100% CPU during 3mn each time I save?